# Loading Packages on MAC

Tags: r, rgl, install.packages, broom

Training a `neuralnetwork()` on my PC has dragged on for more than 24 hours at this point, but that's another problem. While that runs, I downloaded R studio on my MAC (today) to run other code simultaneously; but, I can't get it set up. The same Packages I used on my PC won't load on this MAC. Such is the case for the following poackages:

```
library(mice)
library(dlookr)
library(rgl)
```

Let's zoom in on `dlookr`:

```
> library(dlookr)
Loading required package: mice
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘broom’
Error: package ‘mice’ could not be loaded
```

It looks like if I can resolve `mice`, I'll get 2-for-1. Here's what that says:

```
    > library(mice)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘broom’
```

On my PC this worked without `broom`, but whatever, I'll play along.

```
> install.packages("broom")

  There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
broom  0.5.5  0.7.0             FALSE

installing the source package ‘broom’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 604195 bytes (590 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 590 KB

* installing *source* package ‘broom’ ...
** package ‘broom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error : object ‘pivot_longer’ is not exported by 'namespace:tidyr'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘broom’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/broom’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/yl/tb3dwr4x5gd79c_lbr_krp9h0000gn/T/RtmpK9gAxy/downloaded_packages’
```

and then...

```
> library(broom)
Error in library(broom) : there is no package called ‘broom’
```

If I can install and load `broom`, will I be able to load `mice` and `dlookr`? And more importantly, why can't I install and load `broom`??

I've noticed, in installing and loading some of the other packages I use, that some of them, similar to `broom`, had a binary and source version available. However, unlike `broom`, they gave me an option as to which one I wanted to install. In those cases, those packages too would not load if I chose to install the source version. I had to go back and install the alternative version of those packages, something else I never had to worry about on my PC. I don't know what the technical difference is between these two versions, but could it be that `broom` has, by default, installed an ineffective version of itself? And if so, how can I select and install the other version?

It looks like `rgl` is another library with a source and binary version available. `rgl` gives me the option to choose which one to install; however, neither work. Heren is R installing and failing to load the binary version:

```
> install.packages("rgl")

  There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
      binary   source needs_compilation
rgl 0.100.50 0.100.54              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) no
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/rgl_0.100.50.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4709273 bytes (4.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.5 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/yl/tb3dwr4x5gd79c_lbr_krp9h0000gn/T//RtmpK9gAxy/downloaded_packages
> library(rgl)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: NULL
  error:    Loading rgl's DLL failed. 
    On MacOS, rgl depends on XQuartz, which you can download from xquartz.org.
```

And here it is installing and failing to load the source version:

```
> install.packages("rgl")

  There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
      binary   source needs_compilation
rgl 0.100.50 0.100.54              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘rgl’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgl_0.100.54.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2952743 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for gcc... (cached) clang
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for libpng-config... no
checking libpng... checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking png.h usability... no
checking png.h presence... no
checking for png.h... no
checking for png_read_update_info in -lpng... no
configure: libpng header and lib found
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/yl/tb3dwr4x5gd79c_lbr_krp9h0000gn/T/RtmpK9gAxy/downloaded_packages’
> library(rgl)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: NULL
  error:    Loading rgl's DLL failed. 
    On MacOS, rgl depends on XQuartz, which you can download from xquartz.org.
```

What's going on here?  Is this related to the failure to load `broom`, `mice`, and `dlookr`? Thanks for your help!

EDIT

I re-downloaded R, and now `mice` loads fine; but, `dlookr` and `rgl` still won't.

```
> library(dlookr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dlookr’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org
```

and

```
> library(rgl)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: NULL
  error:    Loading rgl's DLL failed. 
    On MacOS, rgl depends on XQuartz, which you can download from xquartz.org.
```

I tried to download `XQuartz`, but:

```
> install.packages("XQuartz")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘XQuartz’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

Do I need to go back and install an older version of R to get this to work??

Comment: A MAC  is a " media access control" tool. A Mac is an Apple computer. Yes it matters.

Comment: Meanwhile, check out online archives of the r-sig-mac mailing list.  Issues like this are well covered there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed to download and install XQuartz, from xquartz.org, to get some of these packages to run on a MAC.